# Hibernate + Apache Tomcat. Embedded database relative path

Tags: java, apache, hibernate, tomcat, h2

I am using embedded (H2) database with Hibernate and Apache Tomcat, but if I configure relative path in hibernate.cfg.xml like this:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:.\MyDataBase</property>
```

this path will be like %Tomcat_directory%\bin\MyDataBase

But I need to specify project directory to store data in project resources. How can I do this?

Comment: Why you do not use an absolute path  e.g.  `c:\path\to\database ?

Answer (score 0):

If u are using maven u could setup system property and use it,
something like

```
<project>
    ...
<properties>
<property>
    <db.jdbc.url>${project.basedir}/MyDatabase</db.jdbc.url>
</property>
..
```

and

```
<property name="connection.url">${db.jdbc.url}</property>
```

Comment: This seems to rely on the path of the user who is building the application. Is there a way to configure the embedded database with a relative path that can be shipped and run the same on anyone's system?